# Infinitely real-differentiable function with $f(0)=0$ but $\int_{\partial B_1(0)}\frac{f(z)}{z}dz\ne0$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration

I'm searching for a infinitely real-differentiable function $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ with $f(0)=0$ but $$(*)\;\;\;\;\;\int_{\partial B_1(0)}\frac{f(z)}{z}dz\ne0$$
where $$B_r(z_0):=\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z-z_0|<r\right\}$$ Cauchy's integral formula yields that $f$ can't be holomorphic.

---

**In addition**: I want to show that $(*)$ holds, if $f$ is holomorphic and $\text{Re}(f(z))>0$ for all $z\in\partial B_1(0)$.

Comment: @SantoshLinkha It can't be an holomorphic function because of cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: @oxbadfood It *can't* be.

Comment: @SantoshLinkha You forgot to multiply by the derivative of the parametrization.

Comment: @SantoshLinkha If $f:G\to\mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic with $0\in G$ and $r>0$ with $\overline{B_r(0)}\subset G$, Cauchy's integral formula yields $$f(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial B_r(0)}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta}$$

Comment: @GitGud $f$ is a function $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$. The term "real-differentiable" means, that $\text{Re }f$ and $\text{Im }f$ are differentiable (considered as functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: @SantoshLinkha May I suggest, you, me and the OP delete all these useless comments?

Comment: @GitGud I've deleted my comments.

Comment: @oxbadfood The edit confuses me, $f$ can't be holomorphic. I deleted my answer because, as you pointed out, I had forgotten about one of the conditions.

Comment: @GitGud Maybe it's too confusing. I will update my question. The horizontal rule should point out, that the above and the below are separate. First I need a function $f$ that is infinitely real-differentiable with $f(0)=0$, but the given integral is $\ne 0$. Then, I want to show, that this integral is always $\ne 0$ when $f$ is holomorphic and $\Re(f(z))>0$ for all $z\in\partial B_1(0)$. These questions are so strongly related, that I didn't want to ask two different questions.

Comment: Well, the second part follows easily from Cauchy's integral formula. Do you see how?

Comment: @GitGud Would I ask if I can see it? ;)

Comment: @oxbadfood Forget it, I misread something. Sorry.

Comment: @GitGud No problem, not that easy as it looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $f(z):=|z|^2=x^2+y^2$. Then $f(0)=0$, and $f(z)=1$ when $|z|=1$. It follows that
$$\int_{\partial D}{f(z)\over z}\ dz=\int_0^{2\pi}{1\over e^{it}}\>i\>e^{it}\ dt=2\pi i\ne0\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic with $\Re (f(z))>0$ for all $z\in \partial B_1(0)$. By definition it holds $$I:=\int_{\partial B_1(0)}\frac{f(\zeta )}{\zeta}d\zeta =i\int_0^{2\pi}f(e^{it})dt$$ Since $e^{it}\in \partial B_1(0)$ for all $t\in [0,2\pi]$ we should be able to conclude $I\ne 0$.